# depth information from Astra camera

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, depth, astra

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to get the distance to the defined object by using Astra camera with /camera/depth/image_raw topic. By using OpenCV library and RGB image from topic /camera/rgb/image_raw I have defined the object and get the center position of the object. Now I want to get the distance to that center, I read that the depth_image with `32FC1` encoding from depth topic gives you the distance of each pixel in meters. But when I am trying to do that in that way:
`depth = depth_image[self.position[0], self.position[1]]` I got strange value like 1169 or the values which are very close to it regardless of the distance.

Could someone help me
regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320235/depth-information-from-astra-camera/) by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 166 on 2019-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that I mixed up height and width in the image.

---

Originally posted by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) with karma: 166 on 2019-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0